# Looping an entire form into a MySQL db row?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm hoping someone can give me a suggestion on a challenge I am facing. I am not sure that I'm able to do this the way I envision, so looking for advice from those more experienced.

I have a database table with around 20 columns. It's a lot of columns and unfortunately I cannot change that. The goal is to take a form submission and insert it into this table. So what I have is, the field names are identical to the column names in the database.

To try and keep the code cleaner, I would like to just pull the entire form (key and value) in, instead of doing the traditional $varWhatever = $_POST['whatever']; 20 times. Using something like this: foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)

Now my question is, if at all possible, how can I run that foreach loop in a way that will let me put the keys and values into a single SQL statement?

```
"INSERT INTO table_name (Loop all keys here) VALUES (Loop related values here)"
```

Is this even possible, or should I just go back to the more traditional way I mentioned above?

One way I am thinking is, before starting the loop, I could create the empty row and grab it's ID, then within the loop, I could run an update query on the row matching the ID. Sounds sloppy though.

Comment: As far as adding the column names into your SQL string from $_POST keys, it isn't safe to do it directly. You will have to whitelist those strings to avoid SQL injection vulnerability, and there goes your cleaner code.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Or quote and escape them (but that's difficult to do properly, as the escaping must be character-set aware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I came up with. You first have to define an array of field names that acts as a whitelist of expected inputs. Then you just loop through that array to build a parameters array to bind the submitted values. And `implode` the array with a comma when building the query.

```
$fields = array('field1','field2','field3');

$binds = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $binds[":$field"] = $_POST[$field];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (" . implode(',',$fields) . ") VALUES (" . implode(',',array_keys($binds)) . ")";

$db->prepare($sql);
$db->execute($binds);
```

This assumes you are using PDO.

Comment: You could obtain `$fields` from querying the information schema for the column names.

Comment: @eggyal That's a good idea but it seems like it would be extra work. Maybe you could query it one time and cache the column names somewhere.

Comment: @lpangm03 If my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it? Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew: Certainly cache it somewhere if need be.  But there'll be a cost to reading from the cache too (and of course it will need to be updated whenever the schema changes), so you'd have to weigh up the pros/cons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can loop for all keys (eg. do an array_keys), but I don't recommend blindly taking any submission parameter and putting it into a SQL query.

Instead, I would keep a list of all valid columns of the form and work with that, remembering that each value needs sanitization, too.

For example:

```
<?php
$columns = array('column1', 'column2', 'column3', …);
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$column])) {
       die("No data for column $column\n");
    }
 }
 if (!check_csrf($_POST['csrt_token'])) { … }

 # (setup database connection)

 $SQL = "INSERT INTO table_name (" . implode(", ", $columns) . ") VALUES (";
 foreach ($column as $column) {
       $SQL .= "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST[$column]) . "',";
 }
 $SQL[strlen($SQL)-1] = ')';
 $mysqli->query($SQL);
```